# C# pass arguments with flags (/arg1 /arg2) to an exe

Tags: c#, arguments, parameter-passing

I could use some help determining how to pass multiple arguments to my executable. I need to be able to run the executable kind of as follows:
myproject.exe -project ProjectName -jobs job1,job2

My executable is so far designed to run another executable that needs the project name and a single job name, so my executable will loop through the jobs given to run the other executable for each job name provided. I'll then do something else based on the output of the other executable for each job given. For example it lists the status of the job, IF any of the jobs given are not in a running status I'll have my executable start the first job in the provided job names. I can get arguments passed to my executable, BUT I don't know how to separate the job names from the first argument. Here is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Functions
{
        public static void runCommand(string executable, string execArguments)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = execArguments; // Note the /c command (*)
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();
        //* Read the output (or the error)
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(err);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test if input arguments were supplied:
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a project and job name");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: DSJobStatusMonitor <projectName>  <JobName1,JobName2>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not pass arguments as `<projectName> <Jobname1,Jobname2>` but as `<projectName> <Jobname1> [<Jobname2> [...]]`. It's much easier to parse and much more common than separating arguments by comma

Comment: That is kind of what I thought, I am unsure how I would go about starting the foreach loop at the second item in the args array and continuing for each remaining argument?

Comment: May have answered my own question here:
inputArr.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (index < 1) return;
    // Code from here onward will only run for entries that aren't
    // the first entry
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your command line arguments to

```
<projectName> <Jobname1> [<Jobname2> [...]]
```

You can then loop over the jobs:

```
string projectname = args[0];
for(int i=1; i<args.Length; i++)
{
    string job = args[i];
    // do something with the job
}
```

If you prefer keeping the command line arguments as

```
<projectName> <Jobname1,Jobname2>
```

then you need to split at the commas and loop over the jobs:

```
string projectname = args[0];
var jobs = args[1].Split(',');
foreach(var job in jobs)
{
    // do something with the job
}
```